# Trying to achieve a different chapter heading style

Tags: sectioning, chapters

How can I get this chapter heading style? Mine is not looking good. The default LaTex one does not look like this. Do I have to change the .cls?

[image]

Right now I have this one but it does not look quite sharp:

I have found a simple solution. The`\hrule` is missing and also add `\scshape` to the chapter instead of `\bfseries`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterfont{\centering}
%\sectionfont{\centering}
%\subsectionfont{\centering}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \section{Test Section}
    \lipsum[7]
    \subsection{Test Subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, don't change the class file, but it would help us to give a good answer if we knew which class you're using. Could you please include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Skillmon The whole Tex document is very large. I have uploaded what I am currently using

Comment: If you took a look at the link in my first comment, you'd see that there is an accepted answer that shows how you get a minimal example. Please follow the steps laid out there, creating a minimal example is quite important, as it will drastically enhance the answer quality and reduce the threshold to get people to answer your query.

Comment: @Skillmon I added it before you had posted the last comment.

Comment: No, you didn't but that's not important. Your second example is a good starting point for anyone willing to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following using `titlesec` comes close to your wished results.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large}
  {\filcenter\textsc{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {2ex}
  {\bfseries\filcenter}
  [\vspace{5ex}\titlerule]

\chapter{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It did work but there is a little problem. It is affecting the table of contents also along with the list of figures. I want those sections to remain the same, meaning, as default.

Comment: @Delan Then put the `\titleformat` macro after the ToC, LoF and LoT.

Comment: I did everything at my disposal but it did not work. Could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: It did work!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: If the chaptertitlename is supposed to be grey or at least non-black (it's hard to tell on my browser), `xcolor` package's `\color{black!40}` command in the second parameter of the `\titleformat` command will do it. Vary the 40 between 1 and 100 to get different ratios of white mixed in with the black.

Comment: @Cicada I guess that the greyish colour is an illusion, it stems from the thin non-bold small caps, but they are black (I guess...).